# ssziparchive with password protection cannot unzip by normal Finder on Mac

Tags: ios, zip, ssziparchive

I'm working on Xcode 7.2 and target device is iPhone 6 Plus.
I use SSZipArchive from https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive
when I zip with password protection and unzip by SSZipArchive, it work correctly.
But the zip file cannot unzip by normal Finder on Mac with the same password.

Comment: I am having the same experience.

Comment: Same… as I had this with another lib I start to suspect that the underlaying issue is iOS related